# Como solucionar el error undefined reference to ... y id returned 1 exit status? c++

Tags: c++

Este es el código del arraylist, y al querer probarlo me arrojo dicho error, el cual no sé como solucionar (soy relativamente nuevo, adelanto la disculpa por no documentar, etc)
para probarlo defino un objeto (persona en este caso) y la utilizo para probar el arraylist que hice gracias de antemano.
primera parte del arraylist:

```
#ifndef ARRAYLIST_H
#define ARRAYLIST_H
template<class T>

class Arraylist
{
    public:
        Arraylist(){
        Datos = new T[1];
        Largo_T = 1;
        Largo_A = 0;
        }
        void add(T obj);
        void add(int n,T obj);
        void remove(int n);
        void remove(T obj);
        void clear();
        int size();
        T get(int n);
        bool isEmpty();
        int indexOf(T obj);
        int lastindexOf(T obj);
        void set(int n, T obj);
        bool contains(T obj);

    protected:

    private:
        T *Datos;
        int Largo_T;
        int Largo_A;
        void Agrandar();
        bool Necesita_Agrandar();


};

#endif // ARRAYLIST_H
```

segunda parte:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Arraylist.h"


template <class T>
void Arraylist<T>::Agrandar()
{
    T *aux = new T[Largo_T +1];
    for(int i = 0; i<Largo_T; i++){
        aux[i] = Datos[i];
    }
    Datos = aux;
    Largo_T ++;
}

template <class T>
bool Arraylist<T>::Necesita_Agrandar()
{
    return Largo_T==Largo_A;
}

template<class T>
void Arraylist<T>::add(T obj)
{
    if(Necesita_Agrandar()){ // Agranda el arraylist
        Agrandar();}
    Datos[Largo_A] = obj;
    Largo_A++;
}

template<class T>
void Arraylist<T>::add(int n,T obj)
{
    if(Necesita_Agrandar()){
        Agrandar();}
    for(int i = Largo_A; i>=n; i--){
        Datos[Largo_A +1] = Datos[Largo_A];
    }
    Datos[n] = obj;
    Largo_A++;
}

template<class T>
void Arraylist<T>::remove(int n)
{
    for(int i = n; i<Largo_A; i++){
        Datos[i]=Datos[i+1];
    }
    Largo_A--;
    Largo_T--;
    T *aux = new T[Largo_T];
    for(int i = 0; i<Largo_A;i++){
        aux[i] = Datos[i];
    }
    Datos = aux;

}

template<class T>
void Arraylist<T>::remove(T obj)
{
    int cont = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i<Largo_A; i++){
        if(obj == Datos[i]){
            break;
        }
        cont++;
    }
    for(int i = cont; i<Largo_A; i++){
        Datos[i]= Datos[i+1];
    }
    Largo_A--;
    Largo_T--;
    T *aux = new T[Largo_T];
    for(int i = 0; i<Largo_A;i++){
        aux[i] = Datos[i];
    }
    Datos = aux;
}

template<class T>
void Arraylist<T>::clear()
{
    T *aux = new T[1];
    Largo_T = 1;
    Largo_A = 0;
    Datos = aux;
}

template<class T>
int Arraylist<T>::size()
{
    return Largo_A;
}

template<class T>
T Arraylist<T>::get(int n)
{
    if(n>Largo_A){
        std::cout<<"Esa posicion no existe"<<std::endl;
    }
    else{
        return Datos[n-1];
    }
}

template<class T>
bool Arraylist<T>::isEmpty()
{
    if(Largo_A == 0){
        return true;
    }
    else{
        return false;
    }
}

template<class T>
int Arraylist<T>::indexOf(T obj)
{
    int cont = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i<Largo_A; i++){
        if(obj == Datos[i]){
            break;
        }
        cont++;
    }
    return cont+1;
}

template<class T>
int Arraylist<T>::lastindexOf(T obj)
{
    int aux;
    for(int i = 0; i<Largo_A; i++){
        if(obj == Datos[i]){
            aux = i;
        }
    }
    return aux+1;
}

template<class T>
void Arraylist<T>::set(int n,T obj)
{
    if(n>Largo_A){
        std::cout<<"Esa posicion no existe"<<std::endl;
    }
    else{
        Datos[n-1] = obj;
    }
}

template<class T>
bool Arraylist<T>::contains(T obj)
{
    bool aux = false;
    for(int i = 0; i<Largo_A; i++){
        if(obj == Datos[i]){
            aux = true;
        }
    }
    return aux;
}
```

[image: Este es el error que me arroja]

Comment: @eferion veo que respondiste la pregunta duplicada, me parece genial pero te recomendaria que mejores el título: ¿crees que con ese tipo de título podria encontrarlo en la red?

Comment: @eyllanesc voy a borrar todos mis comentarios para dejar limpia la pregunta.